# Combinations of vectors - Norms of vectors - Direction

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

We have the vectors $$\vec{a}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\ 5\\ 3\end{pmatrix}, \ \vec{b}=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ 5\\ 8\end{pmatrix}, \ \vec{c}=\begin{pmatrix}5\\ 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$ Calculate the following vectors and their norms. What can you say about their direction?

1. $\vec{s}=5\vec{a}-3(\vec{b}+2\vec{c})+3(2\vec{a}-\vec{c})$
2. $\vec{s}=-3\vec{b}+4(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{c})\cdot \vec{a}-\left ((\vec{a}-\vec{b})\cdot (2\vec{c}-\vec{a})\right )\cdot \vec{c}$
3. $\vec{s}=-3(\vec{b}\times \vec{c})+4(\vec{a}\times \vec{c})\times \vec{a}$
4. $\vec{s}=(\vec{a}\times \vec{c})\cdot \vec{a}$

$$$$

I have done the following :

1. Replacing all vectors and calculating we get $\vec{s}=\begin{pmatrix}-20 \\ 40 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ and the norm is $|\vec{s}|=\sqrt{(-20)^2+40^2+0^2}=20\sqrt{5}$.
2. Replacing all vectors and calculating we get $\vec{s}=\begin{pmatrix}107 \\ 245 \\ 132\end{pmatrix}$ and the norm is $|\vec{s}|=\sqrt{107^2+245^2+132^2}=\sqrt{88898}$.
3. We have $\vec{b}\times \vec{c}=\begin{pmatrix}5 \\ 41 \\ -25\end{pmatrix}$, $\vec{a}\times\vec{c}=\begin{pmatrix}5 \\ 13 \\ -25\end{pmatrix}$, $(\vec{a}\times \vec{c})\times \vec{a}=\begin{pmatrix}164\\ -65\\ -1\end{pmatrix}$ so we get $\vec{s}=\begin{pmatrix}641\\ -383 \\ 71\end{pmatrix}$ and the norm is $|\vec{s}|=\sqrt{641^2+383^2+71^2}=\sqrt{562611}$.
4. We have that $\vec{s}=(\vec{a}\times \vec{c})\cdot \vec{a}=\begin{pmatrix}5 \\ 13\\ -25\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 5\\ 3\end{pmatrix}=10+65-75=0$ so we don't get a vector, and so we cannot calculate the norm, right?

Is everything correct? What can we say about the direction for each vector $\vec{s}$ ?

Comment: Why is 4) a vector? Isn't the dot product of two vectors equal to a number? @StéphaneJaouen

Comment: I misspoke, I agree with you : $(\vec{a}\times \vec{c})$ is a vector. So, $(\vec{a}\times \vec{c}).\vec{a}$ is a number. :)

Comment: So there must be a mistake at 4, or not? @StéphaneJaouen

Comment: Yes there is a wording problem in 4.

Comment: Ok! Do you maybe know what is meant by the direction? Do we have to calculate the angle with the axes or what is meant? @StéphaneJaouen

Comment: The definition that I know of the direction of a vector is the set of lines in $\mathbb R^3 $ which have this vector as direction vector; I don't see anything more to say, it's not very interesting :)

Comment: Thank you!!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2, I'm getting
$$\vec{s} = \left(\begin{matrix}-38\\245\\103\end{matrix}\right)$$
with norm $|\vec{s}| = \sqrt{72078}$

Rest are all good

Not sure what they're asking when they ask what we can say about their direction other than perhaps that they point along the same direction as their corresponding unit vectors. Or maybe you could describe the vectors with in spherical coordinates and state the angles they make with the axes. Sounds like a pretty vague question tbh

Comment: Ah yes you are right with 2!!! As for the direction : To say that they have the same direction as the unit vector we have to calculate $\frac{1}{|\vec{s}|}\vec{s}$, right? When we want to state the angles with the axes we have to calculate : For example the angle between the vector and the x-axis is equal to $\theta$ with $\cos\theta=\frac{\vec{s}\cdot (1,0,0)}{|\vec{s}|}$, right? For the y-axis we use $(0,1,0)$ and for the z-axis we use (0,0,1)$, right?

Comment: Yeah for unit vector you'd calculate $\dfrac{s}{|s|}$ and for the angle with the axes your working is correct. Those aren't the same as spherical coordinate angles though. With spherical coordinates, you work with two special angles, $\theta$ and $\phi$ where $\theta$ is the angle made with the positive $z$ axis and $\phi$ is the angle of the orthogonal projection of the vector onto the $x-y$ plane from the positive $x$ axis. That's just trivia though in case you're interested. I think giving the angle made by each axis like you've done is correct too.

Comment: Thank you!!! :-)